# Facebook graph API server side login issue

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, struts

I have been having a weird issue since a few days. I have server side login from FB graph API implemented on my website and everything was working fine until recently. Lately, I have been getting the following error.

{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

My login flow is as follows - redirect response with uri, receive code, send request for access token, retrieve user id from response. It is a struts based web application. I searched around for this issue on the net and didn't make any progress. One of the popular solutions that I found here on stackoverflow and else where is to add "/" to the end of redirect_uri but that does not work for my application, since I redirect to a struts action like http://sitename.com/ABC.do and adding a "/" like http://sitename.com/ABC.do/ bombs at the struts layer since it does not understand the extra "/" at the end. Can anybody point me to the right solution. Why do I need this "/" at the end. What is the workaround?

Comment: IIRC, they changed the way access tokens work a few months ago.  The auth code you get can only be used once -- so if you use it via the javascript API or for another call in your logic, it breaks.  ( example: my old code used the auth token once for login, then once for the profile fetch.  it expired after the login, so my profile fetch failed)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @JonathanVanasco . I just verfied the code base. I do not think I am doing a double call. I get the code and immediately ask for an access token when I get this error message. In my code, I later do a https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=abcde, but this is after receiving a successful access token from Facebook. Not sure why it is still breaking for me. Are the new changes to the way access tokens work documented somewhere. I am following - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/. For me it is failing in Step 6.

Comment: From the details on the 12/5 breaking changes, "New security restrictions for OAuth authorization codes. 
We will only allow authorization codes to be exchanged for access tokens once and will require that they be exchanged for an access token within 10 minutes of their creation. This is in line with the OAuth 2.0 Spec which from the start has stated that "authorization codes MUST be short lived and single use". For more information, check out our Authentication documentation. I think this is the one causing this error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @thomasbabuj. In my case, the second request to exchange code for access token is almost immediate, may be in a few seconds, definitely not more than 10 minutes. Not sure why I am still running into this issue. I wonder if others have had issues after these "breaking changes" and how they fixed it !!